# max-height 100 and margin bottom

Tags: css, position

I would like to create a fixed element with variable height that fits content and with a maximum height.

Now I use this technique:

```
#element{
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    bottom:50px;
}
```

It's good, but I would like to make the height smaller if the content is smaller than this height...
I would like to make something like a max-height with a margin-bottom.

Comment: `height: auto;max-height:400px; // or whatever your height is`

Answer (score 0):

`max-height: 500px;`, for example, will make an element be 500px high (or shorter, if it's contents are shorter).  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/max-height for more information about max-height.  You will probably also want to specify an overflow, `overflow: scroll;` for example.

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
#element{
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Note that I've removed the positioning specifications.

If this doesn't work for you, please provide more detail on your desired result, as well as all the HTML and CSS that you've got so far.

Comment: it will not work...I would like to have a height that is 100% window height with margin bottom of 100px.